# Frequency of Earth type cores?

Tags: planet, exoplanet, core

I've read many interesting threads concerning the composition of different planet cores in the solar system while trying to see if this question has already been asked. It appears as if Earth is unique regarding magnetic field strength and interior activity for our size compared with our rocky neighbors.

I was wondering if the general consensus was that most rocky-type planets our size would share the same characteristics (such as magnetic field strength and convection flow) as us? Or if we are the outliers and most extra solar planets similar to us are expected to be more like Mars or Venus?

Comment: So far we have no data the magnetic fields of rocky exoplanets. This is not going to change anytime soon. There are two disputed indirect detections of hot Jupiter magnetic fields, but that's off-topic here.

Comment: Got it, so we couldn't make an educated guess of which type would appear more frequently until we can get more data directly from an exoplanet. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed. Also the connection between type of core and existence of magnetic field inside our own solar system is quite unclear. Mercury for example has a core as massive as Earth's but exhibits no convection that drives a magnetic field. There probably the initial formation heat vs. heat loss through the surface plays an important role, but those factors we're still unable to model properly.